# How to get a single row where multiple rows share the same column value

Tags: mysql

Say I have an sql query that returns the following data:

```
USERID, LOCATIONID, SITE
usera, locationa, site1
userb, locationb, site1
userx, locationx, site1
userc, locationc, site2
```

I only care about unique SITE, so I would like the query to return:

```
USERID, LOCATIONID, SITE
usera, locationa, site1
userc, locationc, site2
```

How can I modify:

```
select userid, locationid, site from mytable order by site;
```

To accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after a frequently asked solution for a *top n rows per group*

You can use a windowed `row_number` to assign a sequence to each group, here determined by the *LocationId* value:

```
with sites as (
  select userid, locationid, site,
    Row_Number() over(partition by site order by LocationId) rn
  from mytable
)
select userid, locationid, site
from sites
where rn = 1;
```